# Smooth MKPolyline to follow the road

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I know this has been asked before a few years back, but all the answers involved using Google Maps API to solve this. I wonder if there is a proper way to solve this now that iOS8 is out and it brought many improvements to native MapKit.

Basically I draw a polyline on the road, which consists of many intermediate points.

```
    var locations = [CLLocation]()
    for item in list {
        locations.append(CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(item["location"]["coordinate"]["x"].doubleValue), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(item["location"]["coordinate"]["y"].doubleValue)))
    }
    var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})
    var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
```

At one time there are between 5 and 30 points on the map. When a polyline connects them I get more or less fair representation of the trip. The problem is: It does NOT sticks to the road.

[image]

So I'm getting "rough" edges from time to time. Even IF I were using Google Direction API, it is limited to 8 ways points and basically decides for you how to get from point A to point B, drawing smooth polyline along the way. Also, Directions API is limited to 2500 usages per 24 hours. All I need to do is to **adjust my current polyline to the closest road**

Many thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the road coordinates (`list`) from currently?  iOS 8 was released 7 months ago and I'm not sure what you're referring to by "it brought many improvements to native MapKit."  Do you know about the MKDirectionsRequest class which was added in iOS 6?

Comment: @Anna ``list`` comes from JSON response. it is a list of intermediate bus stops when it travels from point A to point B. So specifying these points is crucial to follow the bus route. Looks like ``MKDirectionsRequest`` is similar to Google Directions which takes upon itself to calculate route from point A to point B. It doesn't look like it allows you to specify in-between points yourself... unless maybe I could feed it with all 30 points and perform mini directions calculations between them :)

Comment: Format is irrelevant.  Where does the JSON response come from?  My point is: What is the _source_ of the data?  If that source doesn't use the same road map as Apple, this can't be avoided (MapKit doesn't give direct access to road data).  Workaround may be what you suggest (get directions from MapKit between each of your coordinates).  But if any of your coordinates are not on a MapKit road, you'll have the same problem.

Comment: I hear you. Thanks. It comes from a REST JSON API datasource which has nothing to do with Apple. I guess I'll try alternative solutions or just leave my poly as is..

Comment: did any one find the solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some digging I managed to find the answer to this question, although I'm not really sure about its impact on overall performance of whether or not this going to make Apple happy, since it sends out a lot of small `MKDirectionsRequest`'s. For me 30+ points worked just fine.

```
    var myRoute : MKRoute?
    var directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    var placemarks = [MKMapItem]()
    for item in list {
        var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(item["location"]["coordinate"]["x"].doubleValue), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(item["location"]["coordinate"]["y"].doubleValue)), addressDictionary: nil )
        placemarks.append(MKMapItem(placemark: placemark))
    }
    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
    for (k, item) in enumerate(placemarks) {
        if k < (placemarks.count - 1) {
            directionsRequest.setSource(item)
            directionsRequest.setDestination(placemarks[k+1])
            var directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)
            directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response:MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.myRoute = response.routes[0] as? MKRoute
                    self.mapView.addOverlay(self.myRoute?.polyline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Special thanks goes to [Anna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467105/anna) for pointing me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Just searched the whole internet for such an answer. Amazing, thank you a lot! I could not found anything else that was related to the question.

Comment: The only issue with this is that Apple won't allow to calculate too many directions at once.

Answer (score 1):

I used recursive block to get the route for 72 points. always it works till 50 requests then api throws me error.I guess 50 is a limit for a minute. after 50 I have to wait some time to get the api work.

I have used google map to draw the polyline. so the following code takes an array of lat,long and gets the direction and converting path into set of points and rendering on Google map.

//Pathstr is | separated
// Let me know if this need any improvement.
// I am using recursive blocks because miscalculating may throw error on calculating the direction so having this is as a sequential blocks using recursive.

```
NSArray *arr = [pathStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    int pointsCount = (int)[arr count];
    NSMutableArray* pointsToUse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSString* locationStr in arr)
    {
        NSArray *locArr = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        CLLocation *trackLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[locArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue] longitude:[[locArr objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]];
        [pointsToUse addObject:trackLocation];
    }


    // __block declaration of the block makes it possible to call the block from within itself
    __block void (^urlFetchBlock)();


    __block int urlIndex = 0;

    // the 'recursive' block
    urlFetchBlock = [^void () {

        MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Index Value:::%d", urlIndex);
        if(urlIndex < (pointsCount - 5))
        {
            MKPlacemark *sourcePlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[urlIndex]).coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *sourceMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlacemark];
            [request setSource:sourceMapItem];

            MKPlacemark *destPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[urlIndex + 5]).coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *destMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destPlacemark];

            [request setDestination:destMapItem];
            //            NSLog(@"Source:%f ::%f, Dest: %f :: %f", ((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[i]).coordinate.latitude,((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[i]).coordinate.longitude, ((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[i+1]).coordinate.latitude, ((CLLocation*)pointsToUse[i+1]).coordinate.longitude);

            [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny];

            request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;

            MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     // Handle Error
                     NSLog(@"Error for this particular call");
                     urlIndex +=5;
                     urlFetchBlock();
                 } else {

                     for (MKRoute * route in response.routes) {

                         NSUInteger pointCount = route.polyline.pointCount;

                         NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)pointCount);
                         //allocate a C array to hold this many points/coordinates...
                         CLLocationCoordinate2D *routeCoordinates
                         = malloc(pointCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

                         //get the coordinates (all of them)...
                         [route.polyline getCoordinates:routeCoordinates
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, pointCount)];

                         GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

                         //this part just shows how to use the results...
                         for (int c=0; c < pointCount; c++)
                         {
                             [path addLatitude:routeCoordinates[c].latitude longitude:routeCoordinates[c].longitude];

                         }
                         GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath: path];

                         polyline.tappable  =  YES;
                         polyline.strokeWidth = width;

                         //                        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
                         polyline.geodesic = YES;
                         //    polyline.title = @"Driving route";
                         polyline.map = gMapView;
                         polyline.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:[UIColor redColor]]];
                     }
                     urlIndex +=5;
                     urlFetchBlock();

                 }
             }];

        }
    } copy];

    // initiate the url requests
    urlFetchBlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried lots of codes and finally I got it like following:

[image]

Get full code :
https://github.com/javedmultani16/MapKitWithPolyLine

Here is code for the same:

```
  var locRoute : MKRoute?
    var directionsRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    var arrayPlacemarks = [MKMapItem]()

    var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

And write below code on ViewDidLoad():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()


        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
```

Now go for delegate methods:

```
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location

            //Add source location as user location
            let arrayPlacemarksource = MKPlacemark(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
            arrayPlacemarks.append(MKMapItem(placemark: arrayPlacemarksource))
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        return pinView
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay.isKind(of: MKPolyline.self){
                var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
                polylineRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue
                polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2

            return polylineRenderer
     }
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }

}
```

Draw polyline like:

```
        //Add destination placemark...
        arrayPlacemarks.append(MKMapItem(placemark: placemark))

        directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile

        //Draw polyline by using MKRoute so it follows the street roads...
        for (k, item) in arrayPlacemarks.enumerated() {
            if k < (arrayPlacemarks.count - 1) {
                directionsRequest.source = item
                directionsRequest.destination = arrayPlacemarks[k+1]

                let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)
          directions.calculate { (response:MKDirections.Response!, error: Error!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.locRoute = response.routes[0] as? MKRoute
                        let geodesic:MKPolyline = self.locRoute!.polyline
                        self.mapView.addOverlay(geodesic)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05) //MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: placemark.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```